# Referencing multiple local ruby gems in development using Bundler

Tags: ruby, rubygems, bundler

I currently work on an application that consists of many gems. Each of these gems are being developed at the same time, and it is important for us to reference our current local copy from each of the gems.

We currently use Bundler in each of these gems. Currently we are setting an environment variable that tells Bundler to reference our local copies as opposed to the system installed gem.

While this works, it is messy because:

1) The Gemfile.lock is constantly changing when we flip back and forth. This results in errors when deploying.
2) This relies on all developers keeping their directory structures exactly same, unless we also make this configurable (sucky).

What do other people do in this situation?

Answer (score 1):

Upload your gems to private repositores in github, for example, and let Bundler feed from them. Your gem developers should have their repos updated.